# Powershell remoting over SSH through python

Tags: python, pycharm, powershell-remoting

I have a PowerShell command `$ses = New-PSSession -HostName hostname -UserName username` to establish the remote session with the target host after providing the password in the PowerShell prompt.

Now, I am using the subprocess package to automate the same in python. After running the command from python, How to Pass the password to the PowerShell prompt from python after running the below code?

```
import subprocess as sp

op = sp.run(['pwsh', '-Command', 'hostname'], stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.STDOUT)
print(op.stdout.decode())
```

Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, please let me know any further details required @JossefHarushKadouri

Comment: I am not able to join the chatbox, as I am new to stackoverflow. Please post your query here.

Thanks

Comment: are you trying to do it for a python package or as part of a program? @ISK2022

Comment: I am doing it for a program